# Cross entropy giving different values

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to see the result of how cross entropy is calculated, but the following code gives different results.
In one case I used cross entropy formula and in second case I only used `tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`.

```
labels=tf.constant([[1,0],[1,0],[0,1]],tf.float32)
s = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([3,2]))

softmax = tf.nn.softmax(s)
ss_prime= tf.reduce_sum(labels* tf.log(softmax),axis=1)
cross_entropy= 
tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=softmax,labels=labels)
```

Results obtained for `ss_prime` and `cross_entropy`:

```
[0.5116534  0.33509448 0.96646595]
[-0.35425165 -0.04023812 -1.3620787 ]
```

Comment: I see only one version of the code here, can you show both versions, or am I misunderstanding ?  Also I see only 1 set of results..?

Comment: ss_prime is first version and cross_entropy is the second . Both are calculating same value

Answer (score 0):

`tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits` performs softmax internally. You need to pass the unscaled value (before softmax) to it. In fact, that's what `with_logits` means.

It is explicitly documented here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits

> **WARNING:** This op expects unscaled logits, since it performs a softmax
>   on logits internally for efficiency. Do not call this op with the
>   output of softmax, as it will produce incorrect results.